# How do I select the last child of a div with only a certain name using only CSS?

Tags: css

I have been using the following CSS to apply an effect at the bottom of elements in a menu:

```
.leftMenuProductWrapper div:last-child{margin-bottom:20px;}
```

This works fine initially, however after adding more elements in the menu, I realized it was a problem. I really only want to select the last div with `.leftMenuProductButton` within `.leftMenuProductWrapper`

Anyway to do this without using Jquery, just pure CSS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/pseudoclass-nthlastchild

Might want to check your browser compatibility though.

Comment: Thats the closest thing to a solution I think I will get. Alternatively, I realized I can just make the object below it have a top-margin. Thank you for your help!